# What is the difference between Object constructor and Global Object

Tags: javascript

I am confused about **"Global object" (window)** and **"Object"** constructor in JS. 
The confusing part is when I read to similar sentences, one while reading about scopes and the other one when I was reading about objects and inheritance in JavaScript :

1. All objects in JavaScript are descended from Object; all objects inherit methods and properties from Object.prototype, although they may be overridden.
2. Global variables are also automatically properties of the global object (window in browsers, etc.), ..............

What we know is : 
We know all the objects in JavaScript are inherited from "Object" that is the **root** object! All the objects in JavaScript get inherited from its prototype, including the prototype of built-in objects like "**Array**".

```
Array.prototype.__proto__===Object.prototype  //True
```

On the other hand when we are talking about Scopes, we have something called ***global***  scope which is the root scope which itself called **global object**.
And :

```
> Window.prototype.__proto__
Result : EventTarget { addEventListener=addEventListener(),    removeEventListener=removeEventListener(),  dispatchEvent=dispatchEvent(),  more...}
```

And

```
> window.__proto__

Result : Window { addEventListener=addEventListener(),  removeEventListener=removeEventListener(),  dispatchEvent=dispatchEvent(),  more...}
```

I know that probably they are two totally different issues.
So what is what? which leads to which? who is who?

**Is there any relationship between them?**

Comment: Window is a **global object** only inside browsers.

Comment: Scopes and objects are two completely unrelated concepts. You're asking for the difference between apples and imagination.

Comment: The window object isn't the global scope. It's just another object inside the global scope.

Comment: @PM 77-1 Before emerging Node.js nobody even knows we can use JavaScript somewhere out of Browser! So, lets think like this. What do you mean when you say "only in browser"? Is there any other place where JS can work?

Comment: @ Liam You mean "Object" is itself a part of Window object?

Comment: [Netscape introduced an implementation of the language for server-side scripting with Netscape Enterprise Server in December, 1994](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=JavaScript)

Comment: No! Window is an object (full stop). The global scope is a *concept* that contains the window object. Your mixing them up and presuming window is the global scope.

Comment: So what is what? which leads to which? who is who?
Is there any relationship between them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81015/discussion-between-liam-and-amir-jalilifard).

Comment: Not all objects inherit from `Object.prototype`. For example, `Object.prototype` is an object but doesn't inherit from itself, or `Object.create(null)`.

Answer (score 4):

**The `Object` constructor is a function that creates (or converts primitives to) objects**.

**`Object.prototype` is a property of the `Object` function, which defines the root of the built-in prototype chain**. *Most* JavaScript objects ultimately inherit from it, though it is possible to create objects that do not.

**The global object is the place where global variables live**. Like most objects, it inherits from `Object.prototype` (though this is more of a *de facto* standard; the spec doesn't actually require it, but most engines do it anyway). Because the `Object` constructor is bound to a global variable, it also lives here.

Note that in different runtime contexts, **the global object can also inherit from other objects**, provided that it continues to satisfy the usual requirements. In browsers, for example, the global object inherits from either `Window` (ordinary contexts) or `WorkerGlobalScope` (Web Workers).

**In many contexts, the global object is also bound to a global variable**. Historically browsers called this `window` in ordinary contexts, but `self` (originally part of Web Workers) was also standardized in HTML5. Like all global variables, these names become properties of the global object: in an ordinary browser, you could call it `window.self.window.self.window` if you really wanted to.

Comment: In ECMAScript, objects (including the global one) can't inherit from multiple objects at the same time. So the global object only inherits from a single object, which is implementation-dependent, and in general is not `Object.prototype`.

Comment: @Oriol: Objects can't inherit *directly* from more than one object, but they can *indirectly* inherit via the prototype chain. The global object generally does go all the way back to `Object.prototype` eventually, but that's not usually direct; as you say, it usually inherits directly from something else, which in turn inherits (directly or indirectly) from `Object.prototype`.

Comment: OK, but still the spec does not say that the global object inherits (directly or via the prototype chain) from `Object.prototype`.

Comment: @Oriol: Fair enough. I must have misread the spec on that one. In practice, however, every engine I've tried appears to either put `Object.prototype` in the global object's prototype chain, or at least assign most if not all of its properties to the global object in some other fashion. Chrome and Firefox certainly do, as does IE in its latest versions (though I am not sure how far back this goes). I don't have Node.js to test at the moment, though it would strike me as odd if it didn't given that it uses the same engine as Chrome. Rhino does, though I haven't tested Nashorn.